# App icon with white background appears black on iOS only

Tags: xcode, react-native, icons

I'm building in React Native, but I'm not sure this is an RN issue.

Got a baffling anomaly with iOS only. My app icon with a ***white*** background, not transparent, appears black but only on iOS. Android works as intended. I’ve tried removing the icon from Xcode, [image: AppIcon screenshot]

deleting the `ios/build` folder, clearing my caches, re-linking, closing the simulator and metro, and then restarting. Nothing. Still black. I have no idea what’s going on here. It’s driving me friggin' nuts.
And, I don’t know why it appears ***at all*** because I removed it from ios, which obviously means it’s still cached somewhere. One point, the icons for the various pixel densities are still in place. Could it be that, absent the `1024pt` icon, Xcode "borrows" one from the other sizes? However, it wouldn't explain the black background because all the icons have white (confirmed by the icon's creator).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue in my native iOS app where a set of icons with white background were appearing as black. In my case, the cause of the issue was that the icon was set to render as "Template Image" in the code (UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate) . Fix was to render it as "Original Image"(UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal).

In your case, you could check this at 2 places:

1. In the Assets Catalog section, for the icon in question, check that the value of "Render As" field is set to "Original Image" instead of "Template Image".
2. In your objective C/Swift code, check how you are using this icon. Make sure that when creating a UIImage from the above icon, you render it with mode UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal.

   NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:resourceName.c_str()];
   return [[UIImage imageNamed:str] imageWithRenderingMode:***UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal***];

Comment: I appreciate your response. I'm a javascript dev, so I only use Xcode if I it's unavoidable. So, I don't understand your steps. For #1, I don't know where to find the section, and for #2, I don't have any idea about obj-c or swift. All my source code is javascript and Xcode is simply a compiler layer. If someone with React Native experience can help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Refer Apple documentation on Asset Catalog: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/index.html

Comment: I rebuilt the entire icon set. That did the trick. Not sure what the issue was.

Comment: @MikeS. What do you mean by ‘rebuilt the entire icon set’? Did you generate all the image sizes again?

Comment: I posted that 18 months ago. I think I meant just that using whatever icon generator I was using at the time. Sorry I can't be more specific.